# Configure zoom sensitivity in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

Is there a way to configure the "zoom sensitivity" in VSCode?

When I zoom in on the editor it changes the zoom level by 20% (as it says in the documentation). I'd like it to be around 10%, so I can choose a middle zoom level I'm more comfortable with.

Answer (score 3):

VS Code's `window.zoomLevel` setting supports decimal values, so if you wanted at 10% zoom, just set `"window.zoomLevel": 0.5`. A 30% zoom would be `"window.zoomLevel": 1.5` and so on

You cannot currently change what the increment that the zoom in and zoom out command use (but if you really wanted this, it would be easy to [develop a simple extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api) that supports this)